# ScreenToClient not getting the window client

Tags: c++, c++11, graphics, window

First let me pull up a quote from MSDN on ScreenToClient:

> The new coordinates are relative to the upper-left corner of the
>   specified window's client area.

Now, I am basically making a paint-like application and I just made a simple program that checks if the left mouse button is being held, captures the current coordinates with GetCursorPos and ScreenToClient and draws with SetPixel.

```
case WM_PAINT: 
    {
        if (GetKeyState(VK_LBUTTON) & 256 && !bStopDrawing)
        {
            HDC hDc = GetDC(hWnd);

            SetCapture(hWnd);
            POINT lpCursorPoint;
            GetCursorPos(&lpCursorPoint);
            ScreenToClient(hWnd, &lpCursorPoint);

            SetPixel(hDc, lpCursorPoint.x, lpCursorPoint.y, RGB(1, 1, 1));

            ReleaseCapture();
            DeleteDC(hDc);
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

Now, the problem comes when i try to move or resize the window. Instead of doing that, it draws behind the title bar of the window. Correct me if I'm wrong but the title bar is not part of the window client area, correct?

If you guys could point me in the right direction about this, it would be great.

**Read before posting:** If you want to tell me about my use of GetDC, well, I don't think it has anything to do with GetCursorPos, but regardless, using BeingPaint and EndPaint wasn't working for some reason so I had to use this. This just before you burn me for using it :D

Comment: Using mouse and window manipulation functions in a `WM_PAINT` handler is wrong. Retrieving the mouse coordinates and changing the window focus should be done outside of painting. And `GetDC()` is the wrong way to get the `HDC` to paint on, use `BeginPaint()` instead. And it also doesn't make much sense to draw only a single pixel in the window that is being painted, you should be drawing the whole window.

Comment: Like where would I do it? In a separate thread?

Comment: Your UI should be handling mouse messages, like `WM_LBUTTON(DOWN|UP)` and `WM_MOUSEMOVE` (which all give you client-relative coordinates in their `lParam` parameter). Save the coordinates to variables inside your code, trigger repaints via `InvalidateRect()` if needed, and then use those variables inside your `WM_PAINT` code as needed.